# how to get GROUP data from multiple tables msSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, mysql-error-1064

```
tblDailyProduction
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| date |      items | quantity| weight| wheatConsumed| |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
tblCashBillbook
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| date |      bagWeight | totalBags |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+



SELECT CAST(tblDailyProduction.date AS DATE) as DateField,
SUM(tblDailyProduction.quantity * tblDailyProduction.weight) 
AS   totalProduct,SUM(tblCashBillbook.totalBags * tblCashBillbook.bagWeight) 
AS   totalIssued
FROM tblDailyProduction
left join tblCashBillbook on tblDailyProduction.date=tblCashBillbook.date
GROUP BY CAST(tblDailyProduction.date AS DATE)
```

I want to Group data according to the date from two different tables using a `JOIN` clause. Getting the data from `tblDailyProduction` table but `NULL` from the `tblCashBillBook` table.
tried `INNER`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins but there is a problem with the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?, choose the one that you are actually using. "but there is a problem with GROUP BY", can you explain what is the problem?

Comment: What are the data types of both tables? (not what's displayed as that may not include the time)  Is a time component included;  in which case you'd need to cast the dates on the join as well?  I suspect yes given your use of cast in the select and group by  consider `LEFT JOIN tblCashBillbook on cast(tblDailyProduction.date as DATE)=cast(tblCashBillbook.date as DATE)`  and then if you only want records from both tables where dates match, inner join.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to group by both dates, as the dates are put together in your join statement.

Try changing it to:

```
GROUP BY dateField
```

What *might* be causing some problem is that you are doing a left join, so not every row will have a `tblCashBillbook.date` value. If they do, you shouldn't be using a left join but an inner join. So, you are trying to group by something that might be null in some rows, so again, I suggest you just group by the tblDailyProduction date column.